# Editing SchemaSpy Layout files

Tags: schemaspy

I am currently using SchemaSpy to document databases and it is working fine.

However, there are some things within the generated HTML that I do not want, thus I opened up the jar file and edited the template pages within /layout to remove the parts that I do not want. I am unable to repack the file into a jar file without it being corrupted/invalid.

I am wondering if there are any other ways to edit the template for the HTML report generation.

Comment: If possible, add directory structure within jar file.

Comment: I forgot that there was a parameter for -template, so I just copied over the layout file outside, modified it, and put the path in the command and it worked! Thanks!